# Change page with buttons. UIPageViewCotroller

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, swift3

I have a `PageViewController` and three view controllers. I want to move to previous and next page with button click. I have three VCs and when I run, I'm in the second one, (main).

Ordered items: (in `MainViewController` class), and `pageViewController` is an instance of `PageViewController` class.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    orderedItems = self.pageViewController.orderedViewControllers
}
```

`orderdViewControllers` in `PageViewController` Class

```
private(set) lazy var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController]? = {
    return [
        self.newViewController(id: "first"),
        self.newViewController(id: "main"),
        self.newViewController(id: "second")
    ]
}()

private func newViewController(id: String) -> UIViewController {
    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) .
        instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "\(id)")
}
```

this is my code for button taps: (in `MainViewController` class)

```
@IBAction func leftBtnPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers([(orderedItems?.first)!], direction: .reverse, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func rightBtnPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers([(orderedItems?.last)!], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

but it fails, nothing happens. How can I do it?

Comment: Why are you using pageViewController for this purpose on first place. PageViewController is not meant for this type of functionality, you can use a collectionView for this functionality either.

Comment: @SanchitKumarSingh i need that scrolling too. i want to move between pages with both scrolling and button. something like instagram's new update. you can go to stories or direct msg, either with button or with scroll.